# Get error when upload multipart file list via @requestparam Spring

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, multipartform-data, multipartfile

I want to send a list of files in a request.
The problem is that the program does not want to accept a list of files and one file in @RequestParam
I can not send a list of files in @RequestParam
Organized loading of one file via @ModelAttribute and it's work.
**Spring version 4.3.5**

What i tried:

1:

```
@PostMapping("/files")
public void uploadFiles(@ModelAttribute("fileList") MultipartFile[] fileList) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileList));
    }
```

null list

2:

```
@PostMapping("/file")
public void createFile(@RequestParam("fileList") MultipartFile[] fileList) {
    List<FileStorageItem> list = fileService.uploadFileList(fileList);
}
```

500 error(with no errors in stacktrace)

3:

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/add"}, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public Result addScreenshots(@ModelAttribute MultipartFile[] fileList, int bugReportId) {
}
```

empty list
It seems that something is wrong with the configs.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">

<display-name>Spring Security Application</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>rsoft.config.filter.SimpleCORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param> </filter> <filter-mapping>

<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

**spring-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="r"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>


<!--<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" />-->

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
      class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8"/>
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="rsoft.utile.ApplicationContextProvider"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.method.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver"/>
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="r.*"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="messageSource2"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="validation"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<task:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="swagger2Config"
      class="springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration">
</bean>

<mvc:resources order="1" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html"
               location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**"
               location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<context:component-scan base-package="r">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
                            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
                            
expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" />
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```